# Image srcset always loads the largest image possible

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to use img srcset. I have three images:

- screens up to 480 pixels wide
- screens between 481 and 768 pixels
- screens larger than 768 pixels

But for some reason I always get the largest available picture loaded. Why?

```
  <img
    alt="..."
    class="image"
    decoding="async"
    fetchpriority="high"
    width="1200"
    height="630"
    loading="eager"
    sizes="(max-width: 480px) 480px, ((min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px)) 768px, 1200px"
    src="./1200.png"
    srcset="./480.png 480w, ./768.png 768w, ./1200.png 1200w"
  />
```

Here is code:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/brave-ride-79f466?file=%2Findex.html%3A7%2C30

And this is demo:

https://79f466.csb.app/

P.S. I'm actually using Astro:image.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

- your browser cache problem, Try incognito tab to checkout

1. Open your Incognito window open devtools shortcut key F12
2. Now drag to 450px screen or you simply toggle mobile mode
3. Now paste or open your local or website url you'll find the exact size image.[The Refernce attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at9uZ.png)